# Cumulative distribution in python

Tags: python, cdf

I need to calculate the CDF of two data sets and correct the CDF of first data set using the   CDF of second. I've used the below shown code to find the CDF.

```
sorted_data = np.sort(f_o_data[:,0])
cdf_fcs=np.arange(len(sorted_data))/(float(len(sorted_data)))
plt.plot(sorted_data,cdf_fcs,'g')


sorted_data = np.sort(f_o_data[:,1])
cdf_obs=np.arange(len(sorted_data))/(float(len(sorted_data)))
plt.plot(sorted_data,cdf_obs,'r')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Now I got stuck that I donot know how to find the inverse of the CDF. 
Could any one help me to find the inverse of a CDF in python

Comment: As CDF you mean cumulative distribution function? By inverse you mean probability density function?

Answer (score 0):

I would venture you need inverse CDF for sampling

Well, if you build CDF such that you have arrays of X (in the `a` to `b` range), and
array of Y which goes from `0` at `a` to `1` at `b`, then problem has simple solution - exchange X and Y, so new X is from `0` to `1` and new Y is from `a` to `b`